# What is the advantage to using Dense-SIFT over SIFT when using Bag of Words/Features?

Tags: opencv, sift

I'm wondering why most people seem to use D-SIFT when creating a bag of words?  Is it simply that there are more features, hence generating a stronger/more reliable response to the bag of words?

It seems that using D-SIFT invalidates the scale and orientation invariant advantages of the SIFT detection algorithm.

Just wondering if anyone could shed some light on why D-SIFT is more popular?

For my own purposes I'm building a content based image retrieval engine that detects similarities across keyframes of video in a database.  Currently I'm using OpenCV 3, generating grids of keypoints manually.

What I would really like to do is get the best of both worlds and generate a grid of keypoint locations that could be fed into the SIFT keypoint detector to retrieve the scale and orientation of the dense keypoints. But it seems that's impossible with OpenCV?